# how to use cache technology solve complex sql data

Tags: mysql, caching, redis, memcached, ehcache

i have some common sql,and frequent use the result of sql,and add some other condition to select.i need to cache the result.
i try to put sql result in redis,but the key cannot adopt the requirement,i don't recognize sql relation through key.
table

for example i want to put the order table which all type = 2 put in cache,and then i use the result filter all department_id =4. the key redis cannot fill it.
this example is simple,in requirement,it can be complex sql with some table join result.
what cache technology can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you indicate, there is a mismatch between a relational database and a key-value store (or cache).

The usual way to overcome the mismatch is to de-normalize your data. That is cache specific results which can then be retrieved with a single key lookup.

So, from your example, you would cache the result of the select AND the filter in one cache key-value.

Of course, doing this on data that is written then raises the problem of consistency.

Welcome to the fun!